# How to enable gzip compression for CSV files on Github Pages?

Tags: nginx, github, compression, jekyll

Pretty much title. The majority of my Github Pages site is being gzipped, but for some reason CSV files are ignored. This is unfortunate, because for some client-side visualizations a 10 megabyte CSV file is sent over the wire. This results in a long page-load time.

I've tried gzipping the file locally and it reduces the filesize substantially. Is there any way to enable this sort of compression for CSV files? I believe Github Pages uses nginx but I don't see any option in the Jekyll or other settings to modify nginx settings to include csv gzip compression.

I see Github Pages gzips HTML, CSS, JS, JSON, etc. but not CSV?

Comment: You can't... Github pages is free therefore you should expect limits. GZIP is a remote server configuration that uses server-side compression, you have no way of tempering with or what they do and can't compress because GitHub does not allow you access to `content-type` or `header responses` If you want flexible hosting options then host your resources on a proper paid hosting account or alternatively zip them before pushing them to GIT.